# DevExpress XtraGrid is not visible even after I set Visible = true

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I'm using DevExpress' tools on my current WinForms project. The page that I'm working on has a grid for sub-agencies that is visible or not depending on a certain flag called `IsParentAgency`. If the agency is a parent agency, then the grid should be visible with all of the agency's sub-agencies. If not, then the grid should be invisible.

No matter what I do, though, I can't seem to get the grid to be visible. Even after I've given it a data source, forced it to initialize, and populated the columns. I've even tried going right ahead and setting `SubAgenciesGridControl.Visible = true`. No matter what I do it always has Visible set to false (even when debugging the line after `SubAgenciesGridControl.Visible = true`).

Here's the code that I'm using to set up the grid and toggle its visibility (I'm using the MVP pattern on top of WinForms):

```
SubAgenciesGridControl.DataSource = Model.SubAgencies;
SubAgenciesGridControl.ForceInitialize();
SubAgenciesGridView.PopulateColumns();
SubAgenciesGridControl.Visible = Model.IsParentAgency;
```

How can I get the grid to be visible? It is adding it to the controls, as shown in the comments.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just hiding behind another control or set to an offset that puts it off the viewing range? Try never having it NOT visible and see if it shows up. (set visible=true in the designer) You may need to move it to the front of any other controls.

Comment: Visible is set to true in the designer, and there are no other controls that are in front of it.

Comment: is the gridcontrol added to the form collention of control? (`this.Controls`)

Comment: You mean like this: `this.ParentAgencyTableLayout.Controls.Add(this.SubAgenciesGridControl, 0, 1);`

Comment: It's still possible that the control is just hidden. Have you considered using a layout manager, like maybe the DevExpress LayoutControl? In that case, you'd set the visibility of the LayoutControlItem that contains the sub-grid, and the layout would adjust to fit everything.

Comment: hmm I think you need to post more code (much more!), if we are to help you further. I would like to se class.cs and class.designer.cs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `LayoutControl` then try setting the `LayoutControlItem`'s `Visible` property. The control's own visible property doesn't come into play if you're using a `LayoutControl` for layout rendering.